# How to compare two separate types within a list using user input?

Tags: java, arrays, list

I'm currently working on part of a program that prompts the user to add a new cruise to an existing list of cruises. 
The list currently looks like:

```
public static void initializeCruiseList() {
    Cruise newCruise = new Cruise("Southern Swirl", "Candy Cane", "Miami", "Cuba", "Miami");
    cruiseList.add(newCruise);

    Cruise newCruiseTwo = new Cruise("Hippy Train", "Ole Bertha", "Baltimore", "The 70s", "Baltimore");
    cruiseList.add(newCruiseTwo);
}
```

The problem that I'm having is the input for the "Ship name" section of "addCruise" needs to check to make sure that Ship already exists and also needs to check if that ship is in service which exists as a boolean within the shipList.  The ship List looks like:

```
    public static void initializeShipList() {
    add("Candy Cane", 20, 40, 10, 60, true);
    add("Peppermint Stick", 10, 20, 5, 40, true);
    add("Bon Bon", 12, 18, 2, 24, false);
    add("Candy Corn", 12, 18, 2, 24, false);
}
```

The part that I'am having trouble with is comparing the user input within the "addCruise" method to the ship name AND the boolean variable considering the user is only inputting a String.  Currently this is what I have:

```
System.out.println("Enter ship name: ");
    String newShipName = newCruiseInput.nextLine();

    for(Ship eachShip: shipList) {
        if((eachShip.getShipName() != newShipName) && (eachShip.getInService() == false)) {
            System.out.println("This ship doesn't exist or isn't in service.");
            return;
        }
    }
```

I'm pretty sure the problem with this current setup is that its iterating over the entire list and no matter what, it will always find an entry that is "false" making the code act as if the user has input an invalid entry even if they didn't.  So, how do I go about finding the ship name within an entry and then checking to make sure that the selected ship is currently in service?  If you need more information than this just ask and I'll try my best to provide more.

Comment: `eachShip.getInService() == true` won't this solve your issue ?

Comment: Sadly It does not.

Comment: As per your requirement, do you want to check whether an active ship with the same name is already present or not ? Is that correct ?

Comment: Yes @TrishulSinghChoudhary

Comment: refer to the solution I gave. You'll get a flag as true if the ship is already present in list and is active. If not you'll get the flag as false.

Comment: @Bmore, have you tried my solution without using extra Boolean variable?

Comment: Yes I tried it, it didn't seem to function the way I needed it to.

Comment: To be honest @MOnkey reading your code, it makes sense to me.  I'm not entirely sure why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a flag

```
boolean shipFound = false;
for(Ship eachShip: shipList) {
        if((eachShip.getShipName().equals(newShipName)) && (eachShip.getInService() == true)) {
            shipFound=true;
            break;
        }
    }
if(shipFound)
// Do what you want
```

Comment: It would appear using the equals() method has fixed my issue haha.  Man I feel silly.  Just out of curiosity how does the list intuitively know to check for the proper Boolean connected to the ship?  Is it just because of the way it moves through the list of left to right - top to bottom?

Comment: @Bmore we are iterating through the list. We are picking each object in the list and put it in eachShip variable. Now eachShip has the ship name and the Boolean value and we check these values. Does it makes sense ?

Comment: @Bmore if it helped you , you can accept the answer by clicking on the tick sign beside my answer.

Comment: It does.  I do seem to be having an issue.  When I type in a name that isn't an existing Ship its accepting that input, when it should be denying it.

Comment: Yours seems to be working.  It would seem the Boolean you added shipFound was required there.  I thought I could reverse the if requirements and go without the extra Boolean.

Answer (score 0):

What about replacing if condition in your for loop with something like this

```
for(Ship eachShip: shipList) {
    if( (!eachShip.getShipName().equals(newShipName)) || (eachShip.getShipName().equals(newShipName) && eachShip.getInService() != false) ) {
        System.out.println("This ship doesn't exist or isn't in service.");
        return;
    }else {
     //do add ship
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you getting eachShip value until you iterate  ?

Comment: @Trishul Singh Choudhary, Here he already has a shiplist, he needs to check newShipName in existing shiplist. so no need to have forloop, as per my understanding.

Comment: There's also a second condition, he needs to check whether the ship is active or not.

Comment: @Trishul Singh Choudhary, ohh sorry my bad, editing my answer

Comment: @Trishul Singh Choudhary, I have edited my answer could you change your downvote..

Comment: why are you using OR condition ?? It should be &&

Answer (score 0):

Your logic in the for loop is incorrect. For your requirement, you need to first find out if the ship exists in your list in the loop. If you don't find it, you need to deal with that situation. But if you find it you need to check if that is in service. You cannot merge them both in one if condition. Further, note that for String comparison you need to use **equals()** method of String and not **!=**

Comment: So just a series of if-else statements?

Comment: Why can't both the conditions be merged ??? The second condition that comes after && will be checked only if the first part before && is true. There's nothing wrong there.

Comment: @TrishulSinghChoudhary -  **(eachShip.getShipName() != newShipName) && (eachShip.getInService() == false)**  => When the name doesn't match then check if the ship is in service

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `if` condition in your `for` loop. As it isn't iterating the whole list and returns void whenever first unmatched result is found.

What you can do filter all the elements that are a match for your ship names with the user-entered ship name, and then check if the list is empty or not.

If it is empty, that means it doesn't exist, and vice versa in the other case.

Your code should look something like this:

```
if(shipList
        .stream()
        .filter(!eachShip -> eachShip.getShipName().equals(newShipName) 
            && !eachShip.getInService)
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        .isEmpty()) {
        // Not found
} else {
       // Found the ship
}
```

I hope that makes sense.